# Stacking responsive images next to each other

Tags: html, css

the question is simple I want to know how to achieve something like this:

[image]

But I want the images to be responsive (like max-width: 100%; height: auto;) without stacking them on top of each other, got it? I want them to scale smaller or bigger whatever being the resolution of the screen.

For example if the resolution is bigger:

[image]

Or if it's smaller:

[image]

I want the images to fit the 100% of the screen width, how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the amount of images you have just set a percentage that equals 100%:

```
img{
   float: left;
   width: 20%;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6qqxnano/)

If you dont know the amount of images you can use some simple jquery to find the number and set the width depending on the amount:

```
var imgCount = $("img").length;
$("img").css({"width":(100/imgCount)+"%"})
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6qqxnano/1/)

Comment: It's a little bit dumb that I did not realize that? However thanks!

Comment: @NicoPavlotsky No problem. I added a jquery example if you have an unknown amount of images. If this is what you're looking for can you check it off as resolved?